# IF arraylist x contains y statement within switch method

Tags: java, arraylist

The aim of my code is to output a new folder name containing a numerical identifier and date stamp relevant to the previous working day. I am struggling with the code to identify the previous working day. Weekends are correctly taken into account, however i cannot seem to structure the if statement correctly to take into accounts holidays as well. I have included all code i thought was relevant.

```
LocalDate xDay;

List<LocalDate> holidays = Arrays.asList((LocalDate.of(2016, 3, 25)),
                                        (LocalDate.of(2016, 3, 28)),
                                        (LocalDate.of(2016, 5, 2)),
                                        (LocalDate.of(2016, 5, 30)),
                                        (LocalDate.of(2016, 8, 29)),
                                        //test(LocalDate.of(2016, 9, 5)),
                                        (LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 26)),
                                        (LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 27)));

LocalDate getPreviousWorkingDay(LocalDate date) {
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.of(date.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    xDay = (date.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    switch (dayOfWeek) {
        case MONDAY:
            return date.minus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        case SUNDAY:
            return date.minus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        case TUESDAY:
            if (holidays.contains(xDay)== true){
                return date.minus(4, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
            }
            else {
            return xDay;
            }
        default:
            return xDay;

    }
}
```

The error produced by netbeans when trying to run is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at watchdoxgenerator.DisWatchdoxClean$WatchdoxClean.getPreviousWorkingDay(DisWatchdoxClean.java:94)
    at watchdoxgenerator.DisWatchdoxClean$WatchdoxClean.<init>(DisWatchdoxClean.java:32)
    at watchdoxgenerator.DisWatchdoxClean.main(DisWatchdoxClean.java:127)
```

Comment: date is null? When you invoked getPreviousWorkingDay(null)

Comment: `LocalDate xDay = new LocalDate();`

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing a null date to the method?